# ngRoute doesn't get load with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Hey I am new to requirejs, I am trying to use requirejs with angularjs,but I get struggling with dependencies. The first dependency of angular which is ngRoute, doesn't get loaded.
I get the following error:

```
angular.min.js:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I have checked the paths of each files and it seems to be ok.
This is my code:

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RequireJS Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="scripts/js/main" 
            src="scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['main'],function () {
            console.log("after load requirejs");
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
{{title}}
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths:{
        'angular': 'vendor/angular/angular.min',
        'angular-route': 'vendor/angular/angular-route.min',
        'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min',
        'app' : 'js/app',
        'bootstrap':'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
        'bootstrapUI': 'vendor/bootstrap-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.min',
        'hotkeys': 'vendor/hotkeys.min.js',
        'jqueryDataTables': 'vendor/jqueryDataTables/jquery.dataTables.min'
    },

    shim:{
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jquery'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular',
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'angular-route':{
            exports: 'ngRoute',
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'bootstrap':{
            exports: 'bootstrap',
            deps:['jquery']
        },      
        'app':{
            deps: ['jquery','angular','bootstrap','angular-route']
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
})
```

app.js

```
/**
*  Module
*
* Description
*/
define(['jquery','angular','bootstrap','angular-route'],function($){
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('mainCTRL', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.title = "Hello World";
    }]);
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.title = "Hello Home";
    }])
});
```

**UPDATE:**
angular-route is loaded properly using requirejs. The problem is that when I call $routeProvider it doesn't work properly as expected and I get another module errors such as:
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=ReferenceErr…0%20at%20http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A49849%2Fscripts%2Fjs%2Fmain.js%3A36%3A13

```
define(['jquery','angular','bootstrap','angular-route'],function($){
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/home", angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            controllerUrl: 'ctrl/home'
        }))
    });
    app.controller('mainCTRL', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $("#title").text("I have change the title");
        console.log("$('#title').val()",$("#title").text());
        $scope.title = "Hello World";
    }]);
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.title = "Hello Home";
    }])
});
```

Comment: still doesn't work, angular-route doesn't get loaded at all.

Comment: please help, any advice will be welcome